# Is it possible to have a master branch containing submodules of branches from the same repository?

Tags: git

I want to have one repository where master is composed of the code from its own branches.

The use case is that the repository is going to contain sample code in a number of different languages that will be developed independently, but will have shared tests, scripts and configuration to deal with third-party continuous integration.

Is this possible? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I ultimately went with:

```
# Enter desired directory
cd ~/Documents/GitHub/

# Create a directory to contain the branches
mkdir Branches-as-Submodules

# Enter directory
cd Branches-as-Submodules

# Clone
git clone https://github.com/brianjenkins94/Branches-as-Submodules.git master

# Create a branch module
git checkout project1
git push --set-upstream origin project1

# Two for good measure
git checkout project2
git push --set-upstream origin project2

# Clone branches
git clone --branch project1 https://github.com/brianjenkins94/Branches-as-Submodules.git project1
git clone --branch project2 https://github.com/brianjenkins94/Branches-as-Submodules.git project2

# Enter master
cd master

# Configure submodule(s)
git submodule add --branch project1 https://github.com/brianjenkins94/Branches-as-Submodules.git project1
git submodule add --branch project2 https://github.com/brianjenkins94/Branches-as-Submodules.git project2

# Add changes
git add .

# Commit changes
git commit -m "Added submodule(s)"

# Push changes
git push origin master:master

# Feel free to make changes to any branch at this point (not using checkout)
# But at some point come back to master and run:
git submodule update --remote
git add .
git commit -m "Updated submodule(s)"
git push origin master:master

# Final note: In the installation instructions of your README, have the consumer use:
git clone --recursive https://github.com/brianjenkins94/Branches-as-Submodules.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do that very simple. Just add submodules -> specifiy your current repository as source link -> and switch to needed branch. 
But, in order not to have confusions, maybe it worth to change structure of your current repository? Put shared tests, scripts, etc. to separate repository; then create repositories for those sample code in different languages -> add as submodules repository with shared content -> and use these repositories as submodules in your main repository.
Or, sample code could be developed in the same separate repository, but in different branches. Then you'll have 3 repositories: main, repo with sample codes, and repo with shared content.